# When I flag a question as a duplicate it says 404

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions, flag-dialog

We are having an error with the flag as duplicate radio box. It never fills out, but just says 404. If one  of the developers could take a look at this, that would be great.

Comment: Works fine for me. Could you maybe try and activate your brower's dev tools console, refresh the page and try again? Should have more details about the problem in there.

Comment: I looked again, and activated the console, but it made no difference. I just feel bad because I am having to flag as "other", instead of duplicate.

Comment: Eh, don't do that that'll annoy the mods. Leave a comment, other people will pick it up. Nothing shows up in the dev console?

Comment: Nothing in the dev console. I wish I could leave a comment, but my reputation is only 42 right now.

Comment: Does this happen to you on SE sites other than Stack Overflow?

Comment: [Certainly don't](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18393238/474189) [post answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18400868/474189) just to indicate a duplicate. Just provide a few good answers and you'll have the rep necessary to comment in no time.

Comment: I don't know what other sites it is on, as Stack Overflow is the only one I can flag on.

Comment: I did give that answer not only to indicate a duplicate. I did provide it with a link and code

Comment: @TJSDesigned: that answer doesn't have any original content. Without the link, it's just "yes you can do that" which isn't helpful. Don't post that type of answer.

Comment: Did you try reloading the page? I had that happen recently, and it turned out the post I was trying to flag had been deleted between my loading the page and clicking Flag.

Comment: ok. Thank you all for the suggestions. I want to be a good helpful member